# application get hung while freelibrary

Tags: c++, windows

I got a crashdump generated by drwtsn32 on site, which show that the application is blocked while invoking system API FreeLibrary.
Here's the class stack:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
06f0fc14 7c827d29 7c83d266 00000718 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet (FPO: [0,0,0])
06f0fc18 7c83d266 00000718 00000000 00000000 ntdll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
06f0fc54 7c83d2b1 00000718 00000004 00000000 ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x1a3 (FPO: [2,7,4])
06f0fc74 7c839874 7c8897a0 00000000 00000000 ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8 (FPO: [1,1,0])
06f0fd7c 77e6b1bb 014e0000 00000000 02a67430 ntdll!LdrUnloadDll+0x35 (FPO: [SEH])
06f0fd90 005e8cdd 014e0000 02a4bc88 06f0fdbc kernel32!FreeLibrary+0x41 (FPO: [1,0,0])
....
```

I noticed the line ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8 (FPO: [1,1,0]), and I think this should be critical_section relative. So I used dt command in windbg to show the CRITICAL_SECTION information about it

```
0:037> dt 7c8897a0 RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
SiteAdminSvc!RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION
   +0x000 DebugInfo        : 0x7c8897c0 _RTL_CRITICAL_SECTION_DEBUG
   +0x004 LockCount        : -18
   +0x008 RecursionCount   : 1
   +0x00c OwningThread     : 0x00002098 
   +0x010 LockSemaphore    : 0x00000718 
   +0x014 SpinCount        : 0
```

the line +0x00c OwningThread     : 0x00002098 show that critical_section was held by thread 0x2098, but it's so strange that I can't even find such a thread in thread list.

Is there any other method to find out why FreeLibrary get blocked ?

PS: there is an another story about the hung. If I debug the application using remote debugger, no hung is met. But if I start the application on the server machine. it does
Thanks very much

Comment: Where in your program is FreeLibrary called?  Are you calling it explicitly or is it called through a "normal" routine of things?

Comment: FreeLibrary is invoked explicity  to unload a plugin module when the it is nolonger needed

Comment: Can show where you are invoking it?

Comment: ntdll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection+0x1a3 (FPO: [2,7,4])
    ntdll!RtlEnterCriticalSection+0xa8 (FPO: [1,1,0])
    ntdll!LdrUnloadDll+0x35 (FPO: [SEH])
    kernel32!FreeLibrary+0x41 (FPO: [1,0,0])
    ZQCommonStlp!ZQ::common::DynSharedObj::free+0x1d 
    ZQCommonStlp!ZQ::common::DynSharedObj::~DynSharedObj+0x4d 
    ZQCommonStlp!ZQ::common::DynSharedObj::`vector deleting destructor'+0x50 
    SiteAdminSvc!EventSenderManager::DestroyEventSenderEnvironment+0x1d8 
      Above stack, from the code view: FreeLibrary is called when it's nolonger needed

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are calling FreeLibrary at a disallowed moment in time (like DllMain)

[Why not call FreeLibrary from entry point function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903008/why-not-call-freelibrary-from-entry-point-function)

MSDN: [loaderLock MDA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172219.aspx)

[> However, I 
apparently cannot call FreeLibrary from the DllMain PROCESS_DETACH event](http://www.ureader.com/msg/14741992.aspx)